# How to create an error handling function for JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, error-handling, typeerror

I'm trying to minimize duplicate code like:

```
let name = "";
try {
  name = data[" "][0][" "][0][" "][0][" "][1][" "][0][" "][1]["C"];
} catch (error) {
  if (error instanceof TypeError) {
    console.log("name TypeError");
  }
}
```

I thought about creating a function that I can pass it the JSON parameter (`data` variable) with the path (i.e. `data[" "][0][" "][0][" "][0][" "][1][" "][0][" "][1]["C"]`) so the error handling will be in the function and I will not have to duplicate the `try catch` every time (I extract data from that JSON a lot).

But I cannot find a proper way to do it. Would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could be using something like JsonPath: https://www.npmjs.com/package/JSONPath
This library handles all the exceptions itself.